# Changing the color of the Inactive Tab Color in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

In my application, I want to keep the color of the active tab as red and the color of the inactive tab as blue.

Here is the styling:

```
newStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    '&$selected': {
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },
}
```

And here is the render function:

```
<Tabs
    variant="fullWidth"
    value={this.state.value}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        this.setState({ value: newValue })
    }}
    aria-label="simple tabs example">
    {
        this.props.devices.map((device, itr) => {
            let alertsCount = this.props.alerts ? this.props.alerts.count ? this.props.alerts.count[device.id] : 0 : 0
            return <Tab className = {classes.newStyle} label={<Badge variant="dot" badgeContent={alertsCount} color="secondary">{device.machineName}</Badge>} {...a11yProps(itr)} />
        })
    }
</Tabs>
```

As you can see, I'm calling the style using `classes.newStyle` and after calling it the color of both the active and inactive tab changes to red although the color of the inactive tab changes to lighter shade of red. However, I want the color of the inactive tab to remain as blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done by using the `&.Mui-selected` selector.

```
tab: {
  background: 'green',
  '&.Mui-selected': {
    background: 'red'
  }
},
```

[source](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#:%7E:text=Can%20I%20use%20a%20different%20API%20that%20requires%20fewer%20boilerplate%3F)

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-n2cxl

Comment: Thanks a ton for this answer.

Comment: The classname now varies depending on the `selected` property from the [Tab API class](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/).    In my case, I got it to work using `&.MuiTab-selected`

Comment: Thanks @Nicole. I'm not sure what you mean. I can't find where the docs mention `MuiTab-selected` and my code works on latest material-ui (@4.11.4).